# android ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission always returns PERMISSION_GRANTED

Tags: android, permissions

In my android application (*minSdkVersio*n 15), i have to create directory and write files into it. In my AppManifest i am using :

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
>
> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Before creating directory or file, i am checking if permission is allowed or deny, as

```
   boolean isAllow = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

But it is always returning *true* or *PERMISSION_GRANTED*, even when someone set deny permission from *Settings -> Apps -> Permissions*

[image: Deny Permission]

Why `checkSelfPermission` is always returning PERMISSION_GRANTED ? Is there any way to check if permission is denied ?

To invoke permission i have used :

```
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

But its not showing permission Dialogue??

Answer (score 4):

In the new permission model permissions with protection level dangerous are runtime permissions. For apps targeting M and above the user may not grant such permissions or revoke them at any time. For apps **targeting API lower than Marshmallow(<23) these permissions are always granted** as such apps do not expect permission revocations and would crash. Therefore, when the user disables a permission for a legacy app in the UI the platform disables the APIs guarded by this permission making them a no-op which is doing nothing or returning an empty result or default error.

for more information visit [PermissionChecker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker.html)

Comment: If permission is denied then i just want to Toast message : "Permission is Denied, Please go to Settings ->Apps->Permission, and Set ALLOW",    How to do that ?

Comment: it is not possible in API lower than Marshmallow(<23)  please read android doc for that

Comment: if your tagert virsion is grateer than 23 than it is possible

Comment: check app's **build.gradle**  file,  defaultConfig {  `targetSdkVersion` ??

Comment: @NileshRathod, i have tried ActivityCompat.requestPermissions, but its not showing dialogue?

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod, does it mean that if 24 and higher, then it will keep the permission once granted? or it needs to be granted each time the App is run?

Comment: no if your  permission once granted than it will not ask for permission untill user manually deny the permisiion from setting

Answer (score 0):

For those who develop with Xamarin make sure that you explicitly set the targetSDK version >= 23 in your manifest.

**Don't use automatic for your targetSDK!!!**

Answer (score 0):

if your targetSdkVersion is minimum 23 then your problem can be solved by code as below:

```
int permissionCheck = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```